# Currently working on my project and need some help ...want to save my command line info or text in Text File through c#

Tags: c#

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
    process1= new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
    process1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    string strCmdLine;
    strCmdLine = "/k " +textBox3.Text;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdLine);
```

This will run a command on cmd ..
Want to save that CMD command text on text file..
Using this for save but not working..

```
    ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
    PSI.FileName = "c:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
    PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.txt");
    st.Write(output);
    st.Close();
```

Comment: What actually happens? Errors?

Comment: want to save my command line text in text file ..
or to show in richtextbox

Comment: That's what you want to happen. I'm asking what's actually happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("cmd", "/k " + textBox3.Text + @" > C:\test.txt");
```

Also, read [Embedding a Console in a C# Application - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application)

Comment: not working ..
i actually want to show my cmd on richtextbox